# Placing an image over another image

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image like such:

and would like to when i hover, to get another Transparent image on TOP of it.
this is the css:

```
#imagebox {

Width:338px;
margin-left:10px;
background-color:#12100e;
height:221px;
float:left;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border: 1px solid #232323;
}

#imagebox:hover {
background: url("upplyst-platta.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

But it is behind the picture, any way to solve this in css? or i have to fix it with javascript?
The image on bottom is generated from db(later on) and cannot be set in css

EDIT:
I saw this solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/Zf5am/
but cannot get it to work. even though i copy the whole code, what can be the problem?

Comment: how about using Jquery for your purpose, that would be much easier have a look at  http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: here have a look at this tutorial http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/a-simple-mouseover-hover-effect-with-jquery/

Comment: Uhm, what?! dont understand you

Comment: The image i on bottom is dynamically inserted, ill need a function that can handle different pictures if i want it to work with jquery

Comment: Didnt get that to work even with static images, it REPLACES the image, i want it to show ABOVE the other image

Answer (score 2):

Use the z-index to state which order the elements are drawn in.
You can find more information here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

A few other things as well, you might want to add relative image placement based on the parents position and where you say `Width` in the first style, it should be all lowercase `width` :-P

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Tried it, but i didnt get any result :/ would you like to try it?

Comment: Still don't get any results, and css is case-insensitive. How bout' an example?

Comment: #imagebox {

width:338px;
margin-left:10px;
background-color:#12100e;
height:221px;
float:left;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border: 1px solid #232323;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}

#imagebox:hover {
background: url("upplyst-platta.png") no-repeat 0 0;
position:relative;
z-index:8;

Answer (score 0):

```
#imagebox {
Width:338px;
margin-left:10px;
background-color:#12100e;
height:221px;
float:left;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border: 1px solid #232323;
background: url("upplyst-platta.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
 #imagebox img{
display: none;
}
#imagebox:hover img{
display: block;
}
```

and the html structure should be:

```
<div id="imagebox"> <img src="iWantToShowThisImage.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: This does not work, you have it in the wrong order. the image im showing should be there at all times, when i hover the second image appears over it... in your code the image only appears when i hover, and also it is above the transparent image.

Comment: then just replace this "upplyst-platta.png" to "IAlwaysWantToShowThisImage.jpg". Just Tweak the order and u get the result u want, and "iWantToShowThisImage.jpg" is the image u wan to show on hover.....

Comment: The problem is, the images i always want to display is dynamiclly added to the page... so cannot set it in css

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you or provides some inspiration: [jsfiddle example #1](http://jsfiddle.net/8g5p6/3/)

**Update** based on first comment:
Do you mean like this? [jsfiddle example #2](http://jsfiddle.net/8g5p6/4/)

**2nd update** based on edit in question:
Well, the reason for not working is that the hoverimage isn't just transparent: it's a modification of the original.
But it clarifies your wish. I really think my first example is the solution you're looking for. Just replace the url in the style sheet with your transparent png file name.

Comment: That wasnt half bad... But it puts the transparent image over the back image, i want it to go over the back( the .Imagebox). would be really nice if it could be done.